# Labview interop assembly, exchanging Image between c# and labview

Tags: c#, .net, interop, .net-assembly, labview

I made an interop `assembly.net` dll with labview that takes in parameter an image, do some work on that image and then return the image.

After I added the dll to my `c#.net` project I can't figure out what kind of data type that goes with the image data type with labview that is referenced as "`LVBaseRefnum`".
I have succeeded before to call simple data types and cluster types, but I just couldn't know what c# data type goes with "`LVBaserefnum`" or what data type goes with the Image object.

In another hand the `LVBaserefnum` has a constructor that takes an int refnum as parameter.

```
LVBaseRefnum img = new LVBaseRefnum(int RefNum)
```

Does Anyone have an idea?

Comment: What is the LabVIEW code you turned into a DLL? Especially the datatype?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the standard C/C++ constructor in the **Lab View Application Builder**.
If yes, you have pointer. In C# you must declare the class and the usage of the self-compiled assembly (i think an interop assembly) as **unsafe**

Example

```
class FileReader
{
  const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
  const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
  IntPtr handle;

  [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true)]
  static extern unsafe IntPtr CreateFile(
        string FileName,                    // file name
        uint DesiredAccess,                 // access mode
        uint ShareMode,                     // share mode
        uint SecurityAttributes,            // Security Attributes
        uint CreationDisposition,           // how to create
        uint FlagsAndAttributes,            // file attributes
        int hTemplateFile                   // handle to template file
        );

   [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true)]
  static extern unsafe bool ReadFile(
        IntPtr hFile,                       // handle to file
        void* pBuffer,                      // data buffer
        int NumberOfBytesToRead,            // number of bytes to read
        int* pNumberOfBytesRead,            // number of bytes read
        int Overlapped                      // overlapped buffer
        );
```